# Ford Fiesta 1.4 TDCi not starting after engine rebuild. (flooded vehicle repaired )

Tags: engine, ford, diesel, fiesta, tdci

I have a Ford Fiesta 1.4 TDCi 2006 model. The car have been flooded and the had it cleaned and The Head Changed, Pistons and rings changed, have it checked with OBD2 scanner. Everything looks fine. The fuel pump was bad, i had it changed. But the car does not start. we added Engine oil and petrol mix through air intake and tried starting it, it just starts with for a second then dies, on subsequent cranking the engine wont start and cranking automatically stops after  2 to 3 seconds. What could be the problem? The MAF sensor is also not connected.

Comment: Why is the MAF sensor disconnected?  Most cars won't run at all without that.

Comment: @jwh20 - Yes, most will run, but they won't run efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

This engine will not start when dismantled if you have damaged the crank gear timing marks,(bottom cog of timing belt), on the largest diameter of the cog is what the crank sensor picks up to know its location.  its very sensitive, Does your timing marks all line up? cam and crank ? and even fuel pump has a locking position when setting the timing belt. these engines are pretty robust. this car will start with maf sensor disconnected. so you can rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix it. there were quite a few issues. The **injector seal** was not proper and **2 injectors were faulty**.
If the injector is not sealed(copper) properly, there will be compression loss. 
**the car did start without MAF** and some other sensors, but all major sensors were needed.
The timing was not an issue as it was correctly done.